# I want to compare post titles and if no match found then create new post with php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cj

I have created following script to creates a new post from CJ web api if post already not exits with sane advertiser name but script does it without checking post exits or not.
ie. their is no if...else effect, so how can I fix that ? I am new to PHP so please ignore my noobsense, thanks.

```
      foreach ($data->products[0] as $product) 
    {
        // Sanitize data.
        $price = number_format((float)$product->price, 2, '.', ' ');
        $image = '<a href="'.$product->{'buy-url'}.'"><img src="'.$product->{'image-url'}.
        '" style="float: right"/></a>';
        $pd =  $image.$product->description .'<a href="'.$product->{'buy-url'}.
        '">...For more details and to buy it click here</a>';

        $post_slug = $product->{'advertiser-name'};
        $args=array(
            'cat' => $_GET['cat'],
            'name' => $post_slug,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
                    );
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if($my_query->have_posts()) {
            echo 'post already exits';
            wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
}           
            else{

                $p = array('post_title'    => $product->{'advertiser-name'},
  'post_content'  => $pd,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category'  =>array($_GET['cat']));
    $pr = wp_insert_post( $p, $wp_error );
    echo $pr;
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any values come in `$my_query->have_posts()` ?

first check it.

try `print_r($my_query->have_posts());`

then try to do in `if(){ ...}else { ....}`